How to write UIImage extension to add tint color to the image with signature UIImage(resource, color)
Please find my code
convenience init?(resource: ImageResource, color: UIColor) {
    let image = UIImage(resource: resource).withTintColor(color)
    self.init()
}

Please mention what I am missing

IMO, you can convert it to cgImage or a kind of Data, something like:
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(resource: ImageResource, color: UIColor) {
        let _image = UIImage(resource: resource).withTintColor(color).cgImage
        if let _image {
            self.init(cgImage: _image)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

